# ASP & JavaScript - изменение значение єлемента на форме

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Добрый день!

Я хочу изменить значение метки (label) из скрипта. Я делаю так (привожу только кусок скрипта, без инициализации):

> ```
> document.getElementById('_tempLabel').value='1'
> ```

Но не работает. Ней пойму почему. 
Скрипт вызываю из веб-формы: Response.Write(clientScript);
Значение метки не меняется, хотя ИД то же. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('_tempLabel').innerHTML = '1';
```

Comment: а можно сделать так, чтобы выполнялись ASP-команды, потом выполнялся скрипт, а потом сразу после этого другие ASP-команды? У меня получается, что хоть скрипт и вызывается в середине кода,то весь код выполняется, и только потом вызывается скрипт.

Comment: К сожалению не силен в ASP